# how to work on modified elements of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is my code,

```
foreach ( $tick_data as $tick_index => $tick_entries ) {

            foreach ( $base_data as $baseproject ) {

                if ( $baseproject['name'] == $tick_entries['project_name'] )
                    $projects_id_tickcamp[$baseproject['id']]['tick_id'] = $tick_entries['project_id'];
            }
        }
```

which gives multidimensional array:

```
Array
    (
        [1181543] => Array
            (
                [tick_id] => 445196
            )

        [1287834] => Array
            (
                [tick_id] => 437574
            )
    )
```

and in this code, after apply post message function, i am getting different array named message id created an sub array:

```
foreach ( $projects_id_tickcamp as $basecamp_project_id => $tick_id ) {

        $post_message_id = $this->post_message( $basecamp_project_id );
        $projects_id_tickcamp[$basecamp_project_id]['message_id'] = $post_message_id;
}
```

Output of this code:

```
Array
(
    [1181543] => Array
        (
            [tick_id] => 445196
            [message_id] => 5208908
        )

    [1287834] => Array
        (
            [tick_id] => 437574
            [message_id] => 5208912
        )
)
```

Problem is if i am getting more $baseproject['id'] in future then i have to post message on that $baseproject['id'] except on the whole array again. Please have a look on this question, any suggestion would be grateful to me.

Comment: I haven't really understood what the problem is, sorry. Do you want to only react to messages newer than a given tick_data? If so, can you store the previous tick_data and compare it to the next iteration's messages?

Comment: @Iserni: Hey its okay, the array you can see produced after return **$projects_id_tickcamp**, which grab tick_id with base_id as key  before and send an message to them,after send message array hold message id,  if there new tick_id arrives in future then i have to post message on that id once instead of sending message to all array again.